# Using `fbox` with Beamer overlays and beyond

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to make a beamer slide with overlays where the fbox shifts from one line to the other.

To be more precise:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{semiverbatim}
 \fbox<1>{First verbatim line.}
 \fbox<2>{Second verbatim line.}
 \fbox<3>{Third verbatim line with \LaTeX}
\end{semiverbatim}

\end{frame}
```

I expected this frame to split into 3 separate slides with one box around each respective line of text for the slides (i.e. slide 1 had only first line boxed, slide 2 had only second line boxed etc. )

Instead I got this singleton slide for the frame defined above

[image]

Clearly there is not `\fbox<>` command defined in beamer for `\fbox` as it is for some of the other standard Latex commands (like `\item<>` for `\item`) . Can I achieve this with TikZ? It would allow me to have a custom effect per slide  (not just an `\fbox` as I want here) for each line of semiverbatim text.

Comment: `\fbox` does not support the `<…>` syntax, so the first `<` is used as argument of `\fbox`. Use, e.g., command `\only` or `\onslide` etc.. See section 9.3 of the `beamer` manual.

Comment: @smilingbuddha Please don't post just code fragments. Always add a small, but compilable test document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine `\fbox` like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand<>{\fbox}[1]{\alt#2{\fcolorbox{fg}{bg}{#1}}{\fcolorbox{white}{bg}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{semiverbatim}
 \fbox<1>{First verbatim line.}
 \fbox<2>{Second verbatim line.}
 \fbox<3>{Third verbatim line with \LaTeX}
\end{semiverbatim}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or if you'd like to avoid the size change:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand<>{\fbox}[1]{\alt#2{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{#1}}{\fcolorbox{white}{white}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{semiverbatim}
 \fbox<1>{First verbatim line.}
 \fbox<2>{Second verbatim line.}
 \fbox<3>{Third verbatim line with \LaTeX}
\end{semiverbatim}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]